# ElasticSearch 6.4.2 Error: unknown setting [path.conf]

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6

I'm trying to run elasticsearch in a docker.
I got this output, which contain the error message:

```
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: UseAVX=2 is not supported on this CPU, setting it to UseAVX=1
    [2018-10-28T07:45:49,394][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
    [2018-10-28T07:45:49,913][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Xfh9x-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sdb2)]], net usable_space [397.9gb], net total_space [442.8gb], types [ext4]
    [2018-10-28T07:45:49,914][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Xfh9x-1] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
    [2018-10-28T07:45:49,918][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Xfh9x-1] node name derived from node ID [Xfh9x-1gQ4GI-qTT8l6xsg]; set [node.name] to override
    [2018-10-28T07:45:49,919][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Xfh9x-1] version[6.4.2], pid[1], build[default/tar/04711c2/2018-09-26T13:34:09.098244Z], OS[Linux/3.16.0-77-generic/amd64], JVM["Oracle Corporation"/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/10.0.2/10.0.2+13]
    [2018-10-28T07:45:49,919][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Xfh9x-1] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.PdIPS9HS, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -XX:UseAVX=2, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,608][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,608][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [analysis-common]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,613][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [ingest-common]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,613][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [lang-expression]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,614][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [lang-mustache]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,614][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [lang-painless]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,615][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [mapper-extras]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,615][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [parent-join]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,615][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [percolator]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,616][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [rank-eval]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,616][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [reindex]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,617][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [repository-url]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,617][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [transport-netty4]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,617][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [tribe]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,618][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-core]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,618][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,618][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,619][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,619][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,619][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,619][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,620][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-security]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,620][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,620][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,621][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,622][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:06,622][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Xfh9x-1] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
    [2018-10-28T07:46:16,075][WARN ][o.e.d.s.ScriptModule     ] Script: returning default values for missing document values is deprecated. Set system property '-Des.scripting.exception_for_missing_value=true' to make behaviour compatible with future major versions.
    [2018-10-28T07:46:18,359][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
    org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [path.conf] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [path.conf] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:339) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:311) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:282) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:135) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:343) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:256) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
```

My config file does not contain the `path.conf` setting, and even if I define it, it does not solve the issue.

My config file look like this (relevant parts):

```
    path.data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

    indices.requests.cache.size: 10%

    bootstrap.memory_lock: false

    # Log level per-operation
    logger.index.query.slowlog: WARN
    logger.index.index.slowlog: WARN

    # snapshots repository
    path.repo: ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic_snapshots"]

    # path to groovy scripts
    path.scripts: "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts"

    # Enable scripting
    script.engine.groovy.file.aggs: true

    # Cluster Settings
    cluster.name: cluster-name
    node.name: es-cluster-name
    node.master: true
    node.data: true
    network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
    network.host: 172.16.0.1
    discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ""
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

I start my container with:

```
FROM elasticsearch:6.4.2
RUN yum -y update && yum install -y ansible && \
    mkdir -p /storage/elastic_snapshots && \
    mkdir -p /etc/elasticsearch/scripts && \
    chmod 0750 /etc/elasticsearch/scripts && \
    chown -R root:elasticsearch /etc/elasticsearch/scripts

LABEL "image.type"="elasticsearch"

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["elasticsearch", "-Epath.conf=/etc/elasticsearch"]
```

Comment: how do you configure/start your container? compose.yml? env? please share more details.

Comment: Edited the post @ibexit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your dockerfile, in the last line, you're defining exactly that environment variable ES is complaining about:

CMD ["elasticsearch", **"-Epath.conf=/etc/elasticsearch"**]

Comment: Why should I remove it? @ibecit

Comment: because the property is not known to elasticsearch, and as long you're providing it, ES will refuse to start... if you need to change the location of the configuration use the ES_PATH_CONF environment variable. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html#config-files-location for more details on this topic.

Comment: btw: Elastic provides you with official docker images build for easy configuration: https://www.docker.elastic.co

Comment: maybe you're upgrading from a previous version? in 2.4  up to 5.6 there has been such a property (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/setup-dir-layout.html) but removed in 6

Comment: I do upgrading from `5.6` to `6.4.2`... But it doesn't said anywhere that this setting is deprecated...

Comment: In the end, this what cause the program to crash... removing it was the right approach.

Comment: glad to hear that :)